# Wavefunction of a particle decay

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, hilbert-space, wavefunction, standard-model

Lets say we have a decay of $\rho^{0}$, in the following way. $$\rho^{0} \to \pi^{+} + \pi^{-}.$$

Is the following statement true?

$$|\rho^{0}\rangle = |\pi^{+}\rangle|\pi^{-}\rangle.$$

I don't think so because this is just implying that the wave function of $\rho^{0}$ is made of wave functions of $\pi^{-}$ and $\pi^{+}$.

Answer (score 6):

Almost, you're just missing the time evolution. Letting $|\rho^0\rangle$ be the state at some moment where there is 100% chance that there is only that particle, then if by assumption its time evolution brings it to a state with two $\pi^{\pm}$ particles, then it must be that

$$U(t)|\rho^{0}\rangle = |\pi^{+}\rangle|\pi^{-}\rangle$$

where $U(t)=e^{-it H/\hbar}$ with $H$ the Hamiltonian.

Note that in some reasonable sense you could say the wavefunction always had a $|\pi^{+}\rangle|\pi^{-}\rangle$ component to it, it's just that the coefficient was originally zero. And afterwards the $|\rho^{0}\rangle$ component is zero... by assumption (in reality it's hard to get truly zeroed-out coefficients just by time evolution)

I would like to add to this, though, that for finite times/non-scattering situations I'm not aware whether the theory of particle decays is really flushed out. As in, I've never encountered a version that was convincingly complete. That may be due in part to naivety of my own but also maybe due to current limitations. QFT is usually used to handle decays but the results of the theory are almost entirely in the scattering limit.

Comment: But the equation is saying that at t = 0, the wave function of rho-particle was already composed of wave function of pi+ and pi-, which doesn't make sense to me as initially the wave function of the rho particle is not just pi+ and pi-, it can also have other wave functions which after the decay, doesn't appear in the final products.

Comment: The equation is not saying that at $t=0$ the wf is already composed of pi+ and pi-. There is no component of pi+ and pi-. Are you wondering about the possibility that the rho could decay into other things besides pi+ and pi-? I did not include that into the evolution by assumption of your prompt. But of course in general you can get a superposition of different decay products, the pi+/- only being one of the terms.

Answer (score 5):

There exist many final states in which the particle may decay - differing by the final particles momentum, polarization and other qunatum numbers; whereas the initial state is unique, constituting essentially the initial condition.

Perhaps, some clarity could be brought by considering the same problem in more mundane setting: decay of an exitated state of a two-level atom. Suppose that the atom, initially in its excited state $|e\rangle$, decays emitting a photon, so that the final state is (naïvely) $|g\rangle\otimes|\gamma)$. Does this mean that $|e\rangle=|g\rangle\otimes|\gamma)$? No, because the transformation of the initial state into a final state is a process happening in time. We would have to write the Hamiltonian, e.g., in the form of the [Jaynes-Cummings model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaynes%E2%80%93Cummings_model),
$$
H = \hbar\Omega|e\rangle\langle e|+\left(\lambda|g\rangle\langle e|\otimes|\gamma)(0| + h.c.\right) + \hbar\omega|\gamma)(\gamma|$$
We then could write the wave function as
$$
|\psi(t)\rangle=a(t)|e\rangle\otimes|0) + b(t)|g\rangle\otimes|\gamma)
$$
and solve Schrödinger equation
$$
i\hbar\partial_t|\psi(t)\rangle=H|\psi(t)\rangle
$$
**with the initial condition $|\psi(0)\rangle=|e\rangle\otimes|0)$**

Oops... we will not get to the final state in the form $|g\rangle\otimes|\gamma)$ - instead we will have [Rabi oscillations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabi_cycle), where the system would move from its initial excited state to a state with a phonon present and back to its initial state, following never-ending [collapse-and-revival cycle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_revival).

What is missing in our model is that we are usually dealing with infinitely many photon modes of the same frequency (one should also include very frequencies, but I ignore them for simplicity.) Thus the correct Hamiltonian is
$$
H = \hbar\Omega|e\rangle\langle e|+\sum_{\mathbf{k},\nu}\left(\lambda_{\mathbf{k},\nu}|g\rangle\langle e|\otimes|\gamma_{\mathbf{k},\nu})(0| + h.c.\right) + \sum_{\mathbf{k},\nu}\hbar\omega|\gamma_{\mathbf{k},\nu})(\gamma_{\mathbf{k},\nu}|$$
and the wave function becomes
$$
|\psi(t)\rangle=a(t)|e\rangle\otimes|0) + \sum_{\mathbf{k},\nu}b_{\mathbf{k},\nu}(t)|g\rangle\otimes|\gamma_{\mathbf{k},\nu})
$$
If we now try to solve this problem, we find that, as the number of modes increases, the excited state would get revived after a longer and longer period of time, and in the limit of the infinite number of photon modes it is actually never revived.

If we were to describe the two-level system in terms of Schwinger bosons or one of many possible slave-fermions representations, we could even obtain the decay rate as an imaginary part of the self-energy.

Comment: I am sorry but I am not familiar with all this terminology except the Schrodinger equation. But from what I understood is that the statement about the wave-functions that I have written is incorrect because the decay can be written as a sum of infinite infinitesimal decay?

Comment: @AdityaAgarwal a) decay is a process in time, so your wave function is $|\psi(0)\rangle=|\rho^0\rangle$ at $t=0$ and $|\psi(t)\rangle=|\pi^+\rangle\otimes|\pi^-\rangle$ at some later time $t$ (likely $t\rightarrow\infty$.) b) pions have momentum and other quantum numbers - there are infinitely many possibilities for decay, depending on the quantum numbers of the final pions.

Answer (score 2):

The rho-meson has

$$I^G,\ J^{PC} = 1^-,1^{--}$$

while the two pions are each

$$I^G,\ J^{PC} = 1^-,0^-$$

so your assumption doesn't work.

In the quark model, both the $\rho$ and $\pi$ have the same quark flavor states. The $\rho$ is a spin triplet state of the quarks, while the $\pi$ is spin-singlet.

The larger mass difference is so-called hyperfine splitting (in analogy with atomic physics); however, since $\alpha_s \gg \alpha$, it's neither hyperfine nor fine.

Comment: You are not doing the OP a favor here. Of course the $\rho\to\pi\pi$ decay is a $P$-wave decay which gives you an additional factor $P=-1$ for the total parity that makes the quantum numbers balance out. NB the two $P$s in the previous sentence have no relation, the first is so-called spectroscopic notation, the second is the quantum number of a fundamental symmetry. You might have to write the final state in a way that accounts for this if you want to write something that is strictly correct, but clearly that would not at all be related to the question the OP wanted to ask.

Comment: But the question wasn't about the decay process, it was about the "mesonic content", which has been superseded by the quark model. That was addressed in another answer, to which I added the spin-flip. Regarding decays, OP now knows there are alll kinds of quantum numbers and can go investigate that. Personally, I have never used $G$, but it's in the PDB.

Comment: Well, if you were to fire a $\pi^+$ beam at a $\pi^-$ beam you would see a strong enhancement of the ($P$-wave) cross-section around $770\,\textrm{MeV}$. That is the $\rho$ resonance. On that level, nothing is gained by thinking about it as quarks. Chiral perturbation theory actually predicts the mass of the $\rho$ purely from a calculation of this kind of $\pi\pi$ scattering. (And yes, in a typical experiment, one wouldn't use two pion beams, but e.g. a pion beam on a fixed target where the second pion would appear as exchanged particle in the $t$-channel.)

Answer (score 1):

The statement is not true and you stated the reason. In fact the ket could be represented as superposition of two possible quark states

$|\rho^0>=\frac{|\bar{u}>|u>-|\bar{d}>|d>}{\sqrt{2}}$

Both of the quark states have the same quantum numbers, so it is reasonable to write that out as superposition